# Error: Code=InvalidRequestContent Message=The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized

Tags: github, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying terraform deployment of Azure DataFactory using GitHub actions, I have downloaded ARM template of Azure Datafactory from the portal whenever I run workflow file i will get expected result till Terraform plan I'm getting this error for terraform apply command I'm getting following error.

[image: Error]

Would you have any advice for resolving the following error?

This is the ARM file folder structure,

[image: ARM template]

This is my r.la.tf file

```
`data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_la" {
name = "rg-${var.product}-la-${var.region}-${var.environment}"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "datafactory_deployment" {
name = "${var.product}-${var.environment}-${var.factoryName}"
resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg_la.name
deployment_mode = "Incremental"

template_content = <<ARM
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"resources": [
${file("../datafactory/ARMTemplateForFactory.json")},
${file("../datafactory/factory/adf-jp-customercontract-dev_ARMTemplateForFactory.json")},
${file("../datafactory/linkedTemplates/ArmTemplate_master.json")},
${file("../datafactory/linkedTemplates/ArmTemplate_0.json")},
${file("../datafactory/linkedTemplates/ArmTemplate_1.json")},
${file("../datafactory/linkedTemplates/ArmTemplate_2.json")}
]
}
ARM

parameters_content = <<PARAMS
{
"parameters": {
"factoryName": {
"value": "${var.factoryName}"
},
"CustContBlobStorageLink_connectionString": {
"value": "${var.CustContBlobStorageLink_connectionString}"
},
"custcontSqlDatabaseLink_connectionString": {
"value": "${var.custcontSqlDatabaseLink_connectionString}"
},
"MetaDataLinked_connectionString": {
"value": "${var.MetaDataLinked_connectionString}"
},
"OutputLinkedService_connectionString": {
"value": "${var.OutputLinkedService_connectionString}"
},
"CustContAzureBlobStorageLink_01_connectionString": {
"value": "${var.CustContAzureBlobStorageLink_01_connectionString}"
},
"CustContAzureSqlDatabaseLink_01_connectionString": {
"value": "${var.CustContAzureSqlDatabaseLink_01_connectionString}"
},
"containerUri": {
"value": "${var.containerUri}"
},
"containerSasToken": {
"value": "${var.containerSasToken}"
}
}
}
PARAMS
}`
```

I have tried giving template file path individually and compare and change the schema version from template file and r.la.tf file.